# Separar columnas al cargar un archivo de texto con Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Intento leer un archivo de texto, a través de:

```
pd.read_fwf('File.txt')
```

Sin embargo, no logro que en el `pd.DataFrame` queden ubicadas correctamente las columnas

| index | Cargo\tPrograma\tEmpleado\tApellido y Nombre\tPeríodo |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 13\t961000\t452345\tJORGEMORALES\t2020-06-01 |
| 1 | 1\t210200\t46445\tMAURICIODIAZ\t2020-06-01 |
| 2 | 22\t11000\t7564345\tRAULMORALES\t2020-09-01 |

También he probado con los siguientes códigos y he obtenido el mismo resultado:

```
pd.read_fwf('File.txt',encoding='latin1', sep = '\t')
```

```
pd.read_fwf('File.txt',encoding='latin1', delim_whitespace= True)
```

Comment: creo que existía un método para leer un txt. Podrías poner cual es el txt

Comment: No me permiten compartir la base @Christian :(   Entiendo que se hace dificil colaborar sin la misma. Gracias igual

Comment: no te resignes a fracasar. Puedes compartir un ejemplo de estos, ya sea una cantidad reducida o algo parecido (datos inventados pero con la misma estructura que los originales)

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo @Christian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es que [`read_fwf()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) según nos dice la documentación:

> Read a table of fixed-width formatted lines into DataFrame.

Es decir, esta función se usa para leer tablas con columnas de longitud fija, y tu ejemplo no es de este tipo. Tus datos son del tipo `CSV`, solo que pareciera que el separador no es la coma sino un tabulador, por lo cual deberías emplear el clásico [`read.csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
s = """Cargo\tPrograma\tEmpleado\tApellido y Nombre\tPeríodo
13\t961000\t452345\tJORGEMORALES\t2020-06-01
1\t210200\t46445\tMAURICIODIAZ\t2020-06-01
22\t11000\t7564345\tRAULMORALES\t2020-09-01"""


df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), sep='\t')
print(df)

   Cargo  Programa  ...  Apellido y Nombre     Período
0     13    961000  ...       JORGEMORALES  2020-06-01
1      1    210200  ...       MAURICIODIAZ  2020-06-01
2     22     11000  ...        RAULMORALES  2020-09-01

[3 rows x 5 columns]
```

Esto es solo un ejemplo a partir de tus datos, la lectura desde un archivo es mucho más sencilla:

```
df = pd.read_csv('File.txt', sep='\t')
```